# More Efficient Way to Index Match?

Tags: excel

I am have an excel table like this; which is to be filled periodically.

```
         01.16   02.16   03.16    04.16    05.16     06.16
Amy       5.6     6.2      7.2     7.6       0
Bob       7.3     7.8       0
Cindy     6.2     6.8      7.8
```

I am trying to create a formula that will tell me what the most recent set of "complete", non-zero results are. In this case, I would want it to say something along the lines of

```
        02.16
Amy      6.2  
Bob      7.8  
Cindy    6.8
```

I have something like this which works:

```
 B6 = index(B1:G1,1,min(COUNTIFS(B2:G2,"<>0",B2:G2,"<>"),COUNTIFS(B3:G3,"<>0",B3:G3,"<>"),
      COUNTIFS(B4:G4,"<>0",B4:G4,"<>"))

 B7 = INDEX(B2:G4,MATCH(A8,$A$2:$A$4,0),MATCH($B$7,B1:G1,0))
```

However I do find it rather cumbersome and was hoping to see if anyone had thoughts on how to simplify it?

Comment: Why is Amy 7.2 here?

Comment: Apologies it should say Amy 6.2. I will edit it to reflect.

Comment: I think ">0" would exclude blanks and zeroes, so would make it a bit shorter (assuming there are no negative results). You could also do column totals, or use an offset/subtotal approach - they are more complicated but would be worth it if you are adding more than just the three rows.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that your dataset is in cells A1:G4:

[image: data]

You can use SUMPRODUCT formula to see which "column" gives you complete results (remember that Excel also treats empty cells as zero):

```
=SUMPRODUCT(($B$2:$G$2<>0)*($B$3:$G$3<>0)*($B$4:$G$4<>0))
```

The current result of this formula is 2. Now that you know which column should be used, you can then combine it with INDEX to extract the values:

[image: index]

Just remember to update row_num parameter in each formula for correct results (1 for month, 2 for Amy, 3 for Bob, 4 for Cindy):

```
=INDEX($B$1:$G$4,1,SUMPRODUCT(($B$2:$G$2<>0)*($B$3:$G$3<>0)*($B$4:$G$4<>0)))
```

For example, for Cindy you'd need to use the following formula:

```
=INDEX($B$1:$G$4,4,SUMPRODUCT(($B$2:$G$2<>0)*($B$3:$G$3<>0)*($B$4:$G$4<>0)))
```

Hope it works for you.